# Confusing lua return codes from os.execute

Tags: linux, lua, sas, return-code

I'm trying to run the following code in sas:

```
proc lua restart;
submit;
    local cmd = "&cmd."
    local ret_code = os.execute(cmd)
    sas.symput('ret_code', ret_code)
endsubmit;
run;
```

Macro variable *cmd* resolves to a command I want to run. When it is successful, i get return code equals to 1 (why not 0?). But when it's not, it resolves to a dot.

I'm confused, why am i getting such strange return values? How to get 0 if everything's fine and > 0 if something's wrong from lua script? I'm using linux os

Comment: Are you sure CMD is getting assigned properly?  local cmd = sas.symget('cmd');

Comment: I don't know proc lua but the use of single quotes (apostrophe)  `'` instead of `"` will cause SAS to not evaluate a macro variable.  Try using `local cmd = "&cmd."`and see if you get the right results.

Comment: @itsMeInMiami yeah, i used double quotes, sorry, it was just  typing error

Comment: @data_null_ yes, command that i execute, runs properly

Comment: @DenisKudriavtsev Use this:  local cmd = sas.symget('cmd');

Comment: os.execute() will return bool, string, number. Only if the string is `exit`, then the number is the exit code.